# The set containing itself, a = {a}

Tags: logic, set-theory

Why does the axiom of regularity forbid a set like $a = \{a\}$? What is so problematic about it and its nested infinity?

As far as I know, allowing those sets does not cause contradictions and contradictions like the Russell set are dealt with already by the restricted comprehension axiom.

Comment: Looks like too much to "do my homework for me" which is, as you know, poorly received. You should edit your question.

Comment: Peter Aczel wrote a monograph about non-well-founded set theory that might interest you. One question you might like to consider: does $a=\{\{a\}\}$ imply $a=\{a\}$?

Comment: See the post [Non WellFounded Set theories and Russell's Paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313929/non-wellfounded-set-theories-and-russells-paradox) as well as [Non-wellfounded Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/)

Comment: You should improve your post. Please include exactly one question (probably question 4). Please include what you have tried in order to solve it. Also, the tag `elementary-set-theory` is appropriate for this question. That is, however, a busy tag, it will draw more attention to your question when you apply it, so I recommend you improve the question first.

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg And even if it was, I give you my results, so I did the work already, just want confirmation. And for the record: it is no homework whatsoever.

Comment: That's good. However you may have removed too much. Please point out that you are talking about the [Quine atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Quine_atoms) $a = \{a\}$. Also, are you asking *why the axiom of regularity prohibits this set* or *what would happen if we used a set theory that permitted Quine atoms*?

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. I think the distinction between *why does the axiom of foundation prohibit a Quine atom* and *why might we want a set theory in which Quine atoms or other non-wellfounded sets are allowed* is a bit subtle and best addressed in an answer.

Comment: @Pippen that's better, still too short. Add some context/ideas and I'll retract the downvote

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA has given you a couple good references on what the alternatives are, but the question of why they are forbidden in ZF is perhaps simpler: they are not needed. ZF was developed as an underpinning for mathematics, and the vast majority of mathematics has no need for sets to be elements of themselves. Such sets can be allowed with the appropriate framework, but for most of mathematics they simply are not necessary. So there was no need to complicate ZF by including them. Just like classes, you can use a different set theory when you need them.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thx, that is a plausible explanation. My idea is this: a is a set with just one element after all, so it is a finite set. But because of its unique property it is infinitely nested within itself and that looks strange and bothersome, so Zermelo & Co. just didnt want to take chances for a new Russell to come along once upon a time to present them a set similiar to a that is contradictory.

Comment: I'm not sure how far Zermelo and Frankel studied the nature of paradoxes, and what was necessary to avoid them. Likely they wanted something well-founded to avoid possibility of paradox. Russell & Whitehead did extensively study these paradoxes and came up with a much more complicated formalism with a hierarchical class concept, but they still included well-foundedness in their set theory as well.