# Does Cantor's paradox require the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

[Wikipedia's article about Cantor's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_paradox) claims that it requires that the cardinals are linearly ordered. But <s>can't we show that the cardinality of the universal set is the greatest cardinality using the inclusion maps of the other sets?</s> Can't we define the greatest cardinality even if the cardinalities are not well-ordered? The definition of a [greatest element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element_and_least_element) works in partial orders, not just total orders. Also, can Cantor's paradox prove that there is no [maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element_and_least_element) cardinality even if the cardinalities are not linearly ordered?

Comment: What universal set?

Comment: Note that that comment was only added in the most recent edit.  Before that, it was only stated that we need to understand they are [partially] ordered.  I'd argue that the most recent edit is incorrect, but you certainly need to understand the partial order in order to understand the proof.

Comment: The fact that there isn't a set containg one set of every cardinality can be proved without AC: if there were such a set $H$, then you could embed inside it the initial ordinals, and therefore the entire class of ordinals would be a set.

Comment: I mean that Cantor's paradox refutes the existence of a [universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set). But yes, the variant described in wikipedia doesn't the notion of a universal set.

Comment: Hint: What was first, historically - Cantor's theorem or AC?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good argument. The Hausdorff maximal principle predated AC historically, but requires it logically, in the sense that they are equivalent. Cantor could in principle have produced an argument that depended on AC without his realizing it.

Comment: For example, it's not hard to imagine Cantor assuming that a product of nonempty sets would be nonempty, and using that in a proof. But it is equivalent to AC.

Comment: @MJD: Cantor *did* produce arguments depending on AC without realising it. For example, his proof of the Cantor–Bernstein theorem essentially said to well-order each set in the minimal order type possible, then rely on the comparison of ordinals to get the result.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article, [as written currently on 26 April, 2023 (14:51 UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cantor%27s_paradox&oldid=1092640925) is absolutely wrong about this.

You can talk about a greatest element of a partial order which is not well-ordered, for example $\mathcal P(X)$ has a greatest element under $\subseteq$, $X$ itself, even though when $X$ has at least two elements, this partial order is not a total order.

Moreover, given any set of cardinals we can find a cardinal which is strictly larger than all of them. Which means that at the very least the partial order of cardinals, even in the absence of $\sf AC$, is directed (indeed, *very* directed).<sup>1</sup>

Indeed, if one thinks about it closely, $|V_\alpha|$ ranging over the ordinals, is a linearly ordered and cofinal class of cardinals. So it is enough to argue that this chain does not have an upper bound. But this, of course, requires a slightly more subtle understanding of the universe of sets.

This, on its own, will already give you that there is no maximal cardinality. As any cardinality must be below some $|V_\alpha|$, a maximal cardinality would have to be a $|V_\alpha|$. But then by Cantor's theorem/paradox, $V_{\alpha+1}$ cannot exist.

---

Footnotes.

1. If $A$ is a set of *sets*, then $\bigcup A$ is at least as large as each of those, and therefore $\mathcal P(\bigcup A)$ has a larger cardinality. If, however, one thinks of cardinals as Scott cardinals (and/or initial ordinals for the well-orderable sets), this is also not a problem, since $\bigcup A$ is now a set of sets which has the relevant cardinalities (adjusting for initial ordinals, but one can see that this is not really a problem), and therefore $\mathcal P(\bigcup\bigcup A)$ works. If one assumes $\sf ZF$, then one can simply take a large enough $V_\alpha$ to function as a set with the larger cardinality.